# Does the C compiler allocate memory for a variable?

Tags: c

I was wondering that in which stage, memory gets allocated to the variable.
Is it in the compilation stage or is it at the execution time?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, and yes, both.

For a global variable (declared at file scope), the compiler *reserves* memory in the executable image. So this is compile-time.

For an automatic variable (declared in a function), the compiler *adds instructions* to allocate the variable on the stack. So this is run-time

```
int a;        // file scope

int f(void)
{
    int b;    // function scope
    ...
```

Notes:

- The compiler has one (one set of) instructions to allocate all local variables of a function in one time. Generally, there is not overhead per variable (there can be exceptions I don't discuss now). These instructions are executed every time the function is called.
- The compiler *does not allocate storage for your strings*. This is an error beginners often make. Consider:

  ```
  char *s;         // a pointer to a strings
  scanf("%s", s);  // no, the compiler will not allocate storage for the string to read.
  ```

Comment: ok so when a variable is declared, so how the compiler stores it, is it stored in any symbol table. If so, what this symbol table contains?

When the variable is defined, then we say that variable is allocated some memory and some value is assigned to it.

Comment: The compiler calculates the position of the variable (either absolute for global variables, eg `mov ax, [0x06B7D3]`, or relative for local variables, eg `mov ax,[bp+8]`) and places these calculated values in the machine instructions. No run-time symbol table is needed.

Comment: My question is, when a variable is declared , like extern int a; what compiler does, and when that same variable is defined as int a; what compiler does?

Comment: Yes, the compiler uses symbol tables while compiling the program. `extern int a` will result in an entry in the symbol table for the current compilation unit that `a` will exist. However, only during linking must `a` be resolved, i.e. found as a storage location in one of the object files or libraries.

Comment: So `extern int a` means "`a` existst somewhere else" and `int a` at file scope means "`a` is defined here; reserve storage please."

Answer (score 0):

There's a third kind of memory which is allocated dynamically by using `malloc()` and friends.

This memory is taken from the so called heap. While automatic variables (you have in functions) is taken from the so called stack.

Then, if you're having a variable with an initializer (e.g. `int i = 5;`) that never changes value, a compiler may figure that out and not allocate memory at all. Instead it would just use `5` wherever you use that variable in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the kind of variable/object.

Globally and statically allocated variables are known at compile time and their offsets in the [data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) are *baked* into the program. So in a way, they got *allocated* at compile time.

Variables local to function scope are allocated on the [stack.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) You could say that the compiler *knew* about them and the kind of storage their needed but obviously they got *allocated* (in the sense of came into existence) at run time, during a function call.

Another interesting object is the heap allocated object, which can be created with malloc/calloc in C and new or related mechanisms in C++. They are allocated at run time in the heap section.